# finding last pattern in a string using regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a file path as so

```
D:/xxx/some_file.txt
```

This could be on Windows, linux or any other OS. 
I want to find the file name that lies to the end of the path without excluding any non-alphanumeric characters in the filename but also only after the last slash, how can that be done.

Note: Also please suggest some really good books/documentation where writing regular expressions can be learnt.

Answer (score 1):

> "This could be on Windows, linux or any other OS"

`os` module is the only way to go since the path seperator for OS's should vary  (windows is `\` and linux is `/`)

```
>>> _, basename = os.path.split('sdf/foo.txt')
>>> basename
'foo.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\/([^\/]+)$`. This basically means capture any characters that are not `/` between `/` and `$` (end of the line).

I generally experiment and learn [online](https://regex101.com/).